RSA- Dependent Public key attack
Consider 2 users have a common public key component $N$  in standard textbook RSA encryption. The 2 parties have their respective keys $(e_1,d_1)$, $(e_2,d_2)$ respectively. How can user $2$ decrypt the ciphertext $c$ encrypted to user 1?  Please explain how the attack works.

This is the same question as here. The first answer describes an attack against this situation and why it works. Basically if you share a common modulus with another user, know your private parameter, and know their public parameter, you can factor the modulus and reconstruct their private parameter. At that point it's trivial to decrypt anything intended for them or forge valid signatures for them.

A slightly different algorithm allowing user 2 to factor $N$ given $N,e_2,d_2$ is there. For the rest, hint: $e_1$ is public.
